Using sed or awk, how can i delete a line whenever the next line begins with the same content followed by a slash?
Using sed or awk, how can I delete a line whenever the next line begins with the same content followed by a slash?


Seems hard for sed, easy for awk.   What have you tried?

Please don't post images of text; post the text. Posting your example as text will also allow users to copy it and test their solutions with it. Do the leading numbers belong to the actual input?

Would it be correct to say that you'd like to delete all entries in the file that corresponds to directories? If so, one could simply test each entry as a pathname against the file system, assuming you have access to the file system wherever these files and directories are located. Alternative, just generate tho list without including the directories.

Please post the expected output as well as sample input in plain text.

g-man-says-reinstate-monica: i tried a thousand things for about 6 hours and failed.
Kamil Maciorowski: Thanks Good points!
Kusalananda: YES!!  Great idea!!!  Ed Morton: Yes, good point!

With awk:
awk 'NR==1 {prev=$0; next} index($0 ,prev"/") != 1 {print prev} {prev=$0} END {if (NR>0) print prev}' FILENAME

Multi line for readability:
awk '
  NR==1 {prev=$0; next}
  index($0, prev"/") != 1 {print prev}
  {prev=$0}
  END {if (NR>0) print prev}
  ' FILENAME


Copy the first line of the file to a variable called prev and skip to the next line.
Starting from the second line, check if prev + / matches the beginning (index 1) of the current line ($0). If not, print the previous line.
Copy the current line ($0) to prev.
When awk finishes reading the file, print the last line (prev), unless the file is empty.


Could be:
sed '$!{N; /^\(.*\)\n\1\//!P; D;}'

Where (except when the last line is reached ($!)):

N appends the next line to the pattern space.
/^\(.*\)\n\1\//!P Prints the first line in the pattern space unless if it contains one line followed by the same line followed by /.
D then deletes that line and loops back to the beginning with the remaining line still in the pattern.


You could do it with sed(1) + sort(1) + join(1):

First make sure the file is sorted.

sort file -o file


Then use sed(1) to obtain the list of entries to remove:

sed 's/\/[^/]*$//' file | sort -u > toremove


Finally use join(1) to finish the job:

join -v 1 file toremove


I don't think it works, or it least doing what the OP requested. All your second sed is doing is removing the last elemant after the slash of each line. A line with one element (like the first one) will allways get deleted, regardless of its content.
